# how to control spectacle presentation with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spectacle

I tried to get the count of all slides and change to one of them using plain javascript. I'm not into react and wasn't able to find a global object to call some functions on.

Is there something like: `presentation.loadSlide(2);` ?

Comment: If everything fails: `window.location = "#/2?presenter" `

Comment: yeah thanks I thought this as well, but I dont know how to get the count of all slides and get an error if I load a slide out of bounds (would be a workaround if it would load the last slide on a very high number out of bounds)

Comment: do you have any control over the React project. Or, it is someone else's project and you cannot modify React code.

Comment: I have control yes. Is there is no other way around?

Comment: Ok, then if you have control over React then I guess you already have slides count but want it in global object, so that you can access it via `window.slidesCount`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add a reference to your `Deck` component like below

```
<Deck ref={(deck) => {this.deck = deck; }} transition={["zoom", "slide"]} transitionDuration={500} theme={theme}>
  ...
</Deck>
```

Now you have a property by the name of `deck` in your component. Use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to retrieve `this.deck.props.children.length` and assign it to `window.slideCount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.slideCount = this.deck.props.children.length
}
```

Now open browser console and type `slideCount`, you will se you have slide count displayed there. After that you can use following to change the slides

```
window.location = "#/1"
```

Comment: Thank for this workaround. It's not as nice as an api like revealjs but I will take it. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/spectacle#go-to-action-base),

> The GoToAction tag lets you jump to another slide in your deck. The GoToAction can be used a simple button that supports Base styling or accept a render prop with a callback to support custom components

The following code will render a button that will jump to a specific slide in your deck.

```
<GoToAction slide={3}>Jump to 3</GoToAction>
```

Comment: thanks. But I need to control the presentation from outside an iFrame (Jump to next,prev, first, last slide...), so this don't help me mutch.